# stale deployment in WAS

Tags: eclipse, websphere, myeclipse

I'm learning to use IBM WebSphere v8.8.5 for JavaEE development. I'm using MyEclipse as the development environment.

Sometimes when I debug my project from inside MyEclipse, I could see errors like this

```
00000091 ComponentMeta E   WSVR0603E: ComponentMetaDataAccessor beginContext method received a NULL ComponentMetaData.
00000091 AlarmListener E   SCHD0063E: A task with ID 953 (mi-online-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT#my-online-services-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#PaymentResultCheckServiceBean) failed to run on Scheduler WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service (WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service) because of an exception: java.lang.NullPointerException.
```

But actually, there's no `PaymentResultCheckServiceBean` in my project. It used to be in the project but I have renamed it.

When I develop in MyEclipse, I add a WAS server. Sometimes if anything wrong, I'll directly delete the whole workspace from disk and create a new one. So I'm wondering if these ways leave some stale data in WAS folder so that when WAS starts, old deployment got to run. But I've checked `C:\IBM\WebSphere85\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\myserver`, there's nothing here.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the app from the server, maybe restarting the server, then adding it back?

Comment: If you still see the problem after trying the suggestion from @dbreaux, check the Deployment Assembly in the project's properties. This page should show everything that is being deployed. If there are still issues, a link to the workspace log might help provide more info for investigation.